# Recommendation: Textbooks on representation theory of algebras emphasizing the usage of triangulated categories?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, triangulated-categories

There exist some nice textbooks on representation theory of algebras ([This book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/elements-of-the-representation-theory-of-associative-algebras/AA8066B5809D0F556A540400AD3A419C) for example), which mainly develop the theory on module categories (or their quotients). As I'm also learning triangulated categories, I would like to ask for some textbooks on rep theory of algebras which mainly use the language of triangulated categories. For example [Happel 1988](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/triangulated-categories-in-the-representation-of-finite-dimensional-algebras/8B27A25C1ACEFD54EBD51306AFC3BADC) is a great one. Are there newer ones recommended?

Answer (score 2):

The recent book "Homological theory of representations" by Henning Krause is freely available on his homepage: [https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~hkrause/](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ehkrause/)

There is also a book from Alexander Zimmermann on representation theory focusing on the representation theory of groups using triangulated categories.